# In SSIS SQL Server Table Configuration, can we configure connection string of a connection manager multiple times?

Tags: ssis

In my SSIS package, I have a DFT with an OLEDB source and OLEDB Destination.
I have to load the records from the source to multiple destination tables.
I am using SQL server Table Configuration in the package.

So In the configuration table I have multiple records to configure the destination connection with same ConfigurationFilter value.

Is it possible to do this using SQL server table configuration?

Comment: You can accomplish this task using database replication.

Comment: Are the multiple tables on the same database with different names, or different database with the same name, or on different servers with the same database and name?

Comment: The multiple tables will always have same Table names. The tables can be in different databases of same server or different servers.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your answer to my comment, what you want is a loop with an expression for the connection string of your table connection.

Set up a loop to either read from a table or an enum (where you type the values in manually (better to use table)  read machine and database name into variable in loop.  set up connection to have an expression based upon the variables loaded in loop for the connection string.  create dft for data movement in loop choose connection with expression in it.  every time the loop iterates, it will update the connection string and you will be acting on a different server/db for the same table.